# Query identifying duplicate records with different values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in which I have loaded records from 4 different sources.  There is no common factor between the records from each source except for FName, LName, Addr1, Addr2, City, State and Zip.  Each record is assigned a FileID by me based upon which source file they were loaded from.  I need to construct a query in which I can identify which person/household was found to be in all 4 files, 3 files, 2 files, etc.  I only need to maintain one record for each duplicate person/household.

The other tricky part is that I have email address on 2 of the 4 files and also an Emailable field field that is coming in on the other two files.  This is a factor which I need to consider also when maintaining the single selected record.

For example, one group will be indicated by: “individuals who are in all of the following lists: DMA , Vehicle Ownership  and Lifestyle (Wealth Engine) lists. These individuals must have an email address.” But then another group needs to be identified as “individuals who are in all of the following lists: DMA , Vehicle Ownership  and Lifestyle (Wealth Engine) lists. These individuals DO NOT have an email address”

Example Data:

```
 ID                         FirstName LastName  FullName   Address1 Address2  City    State Zip     Zip4    EmailAddress            FILE    EMAILABLE
 06925901SNDCR44110G6520  S Nylah     Watson    NULL       1234 Main    NULL Anytown    ST  10000   2000    NULL                    DMA     Y
 1641189779                 Nylah     Watson    NULL       1234 Main         Anytown    ST  10000   2000    nylahwatson@gmail.com   LST 
 06925901SNDCR44110G6520  S Nylah     Watson    NULL       1234 Main    NULL Anytown    ST  10000   2000    NULL                    VEH     Y
 374977111                  Nylah     Watson    NULL       1234 Main    NULL Anytown    ST  10000   2000    nylahwatson@gmail.com   V12     NULL
 48770181SBRNT 1345M6352  S Watson    Nylah     NULL       4321 Main    NULL HOUSTON    TX  20000   3000    NULL                    DMA     N
 48770181SBRNT 1345M6352  S Watson    Nylah     NULL       4321 Main    NULL HOUSTON    TX  20000   3000    NULL                    VEH     N
 1933990731                 Watson    Nylah     NULL       4321 Main         Houston    TX  20000   3000                            LST
```

Comment: Have you tried any queries to work towards a solution for this? If so, may we see them? You will find readers especially appreciate effort, even if your work is not complete.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how many/how flexible the groups you need are, you may want to do something like this:

```
Select Name, Address... -- Fields you want to group on (consider to identify the same person)
    , max(case when File = 'DMA' then 1 else 0 end) as HasDMAFile
    , max(case when File = 'Veh' then 1 else 0 end) as HasVEHFile --repeat for your other file types
    , max(case when emailaddress is not null then 1 else 0 end) as HasEmail
From MyTable
Group by Name, Address...--same list of fields as you use at the beginning of your select
```

Then use that result set to create your combination groups, for example:

```
; with CTE as (Query from Above)

Select *
    , case when HasDMAFile = 1 
                and HasVEHFile = 1 
                and HasLSTFile = 1 
                and HasEmail = 0 
           then 'Group 1' 
           when HasDMAFile = 1 
                and HasVEHFile = 1 
                and HasLSTFile = 1 
                and HasEmail = 1
           then 'Group 2' --etc for more groups here; make sure your groups are either mutually exclusive or in a logical order, since the case statement is evaluated in the order it's written
      end as Grp
from CTE
```

Comment: Perfect.  Exactly what I needed.  Much thanks

Comment: A followup question:  Although this solution works well, is there a way to contain each created group within the same column instead of a separate "Grp" column being created for each case statement?

Comment: Yes - just add more criteria to your case statement.  I will edit to add an example.

Comment: @Nylah if this answer meets your needs, please upvote and/or mark it accepted.

Comment: Anyway to get a count on each group?

Comment: Yes, you can drop those results into another CTE, then aggregate from it; or you can put the entire `case` statement that creates the groups into your `Group By`.  Recommend posting another question if you have additional questions beyond what you originally posted here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   FName, LName, Addr1, Addr2, City, State, Zip,count(distinct File)
FROM <TABLE>
GROUP BY FName, LName, Addr1, Addr2, City, State, Zip
Having count(distinct File)=4
```

The emails could be coalesced, but you need to figure out an order of preference.